# Assign a variable the value of a string in a file

Tags: shell, sed, awk

I have a file called *info.log* which contains the line:

```
/home/jax/Main_X_1_A
```

**X**, **1** and **A** are meaningful and they can change. However *"Main"* and the underscores remain the same.
Is it possible to use a utility to assign a shell variable a value based on the information in *info.log*?

E.g.

```
MY_VERSION="?_?_?";
```

Where the question marks represent the single characters that are found in those locations.
For example if *info.log* contained this line:

```
/home/jax/Main_1_2_3
```

And we used that data to initialise a shell variable:

```
MY_VERSION=...
echo $MY_VERSION
```

The output would be:

> 1_2_3

Updating question with better example:

Info.log

```
MODULE=TEST
QUICK_BUILD_DIR=/usr/apps/Main_1_2_3
ANT_FILE=build.xml
FANCE=/usr/apps/test/Main_1_2_3
```

I want to be able to take these three numbers(1, 2 and 3):

```
QUICK_BUILD_DIR=/usr/apps/Main_1_2_3
```

And assign them to variables.

Note: 1, 2 and 3 are just example numbers and they can change.

Comment: I think you need to update your question with a better corpus and more examples of your desired output. From the comments below, there seem to be requirements and edge cases that are missing from your question.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this?

```
var="MY_VERSION=1_3_2"
version=$(echo $var | sed 's/.*MAIN_\(.*\)/\1/') #version will be 1_3_2
```

This uses bash and sed.

Answer (score 1):

### A GNU Awk Solution

```
$ MY_VERSION=$(awk -F/ '/Main_/ { sub(/Main_/, "", $NF); print $NF }' info.log)
$ echo "$MY_VERSION"
X_1_A
```

Comment: This works - is there anyway to expand it? In my info.log I have serveral absolute paths that look like this: `/home/jax/Main_1_2_3, /home/jane/Main_1_2_5` I would only want to use the value of one absolute path if you follow? Also would you be able to expand at all on how this works?

Comment: If there are multiple lines, how do you decide which to use?

Comment: I know the absolute path of the one I want to use up until the last part where I am trying to peel the values from. E.g. `/home/jax/Main_1_2_3
 /home/jill/Main_1_2_4` I'll want my values to peeled from /home/jax/ so the echo will produce 1_2_3.

Comment: @mr_sugartaste What if there's another line like `/home/jax/Main_1_2_4`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this awk command:

```
cat file
/home/jill/Main_1_2_4
/home/jax/Main_1_2_3
/home/john/Main_X_1_A

awk -v u=jax -F '/' '$3==u{sub(/^Main_/, "", $4); print $4}' file
1_2_3
```

Here you can pass any username in `u` variable to awk (as `jax` is being passed here) and version will be picked from that particular line.

Answer (score 0):

No need for external utilities. Bash can do the string manipulation for you:

```
$ cat info.log 
/home/jax/Main_X_1_A
$ read -r a < info.log
$ b="${a#*_}"
$ echo "$b"
X_1_A
```